# How to select audio device for recording in C# using MciSendString

Tags: c#, c, audio, modem, tapi

I'm trying to record audio input from a modem which I have managed to get to make calls via the TAPI api.

I can record using MciSendString but don't know how to select the modem as the audio input device (at the moment it defaults to selecting the sound card).

I could alternatively use the TAPI commands to record but I can't seem to get it to work:

http://julmar.com/blog/programming/you-can-be-just-like-the-government-and-record-telephone-conversations-with-tapi-3-1/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you have to detect all devices first, then you can chose it from there. The Code is VB.Net but you should be able to translate it very easily. The Event-Handler is not necessary in your case, I think.

Locate all TAPI-Devices:

```
Private Sub New()
fTapi = New TAPI3Lib.TAPI()
fTapi.Initialize()

fTapi.EventFilter = TAPI_EVENT.TE_CALLNOTIFICATION Or TAPI_EVENT.TE_CALLINFOCHANGE Or TAPI_EVENT.TE_CALLHUB

    AddHandler fTapi.Event, AddressOf internalTapiHandler

    devices = New List(Of Device)()
    For Each addr As ITAddress In CType(fTapi.Addresses, ITCollection)
      devices.Add(New Device(fTapi, addr))
    Next
End Sub
```

You can also check wheter the device is an audio device:

```
Public ReadOnly Property isAudioDevice() As Boolean
      Get
        Return (addr.State = ADDRESS_STATE.AS_INSERVICE) And (CType(addr, ITMediaSupport).MediaTypes And TapiConstants.TAPIMEDIATYPE_AUDIO) = TapiConstants.TAPIMEDIATYPE_AUDIO
      End Get
   End Property
```

From there you can go on with the other example code.

Note that I did not test it because of time issue. Hope this helps anyway.

Regards

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't pick up the "USRobotics 56k* USB Modem 5637) as an audio in. Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Like I said, I can dial out, hang up calls, do basic bits but can't seem to get anything else to work. I've read that for recording ActiveX can handle it or alternatively I need a PCI voice card that takes the phone line in and will give me direct access to functions for recording via the card?

Comment: Maybe you need a firmware update? The Product Homepage says that voice support is included since FW version 1.2.23 (http://www.usr-emea.com/support/s-prod-template.asp?loc=grmy&prod=5637) -> Link to DataSheet: http://support.usr.com/download/datasheets/modem/5637/5637-ds.pdf